# Echo the combined size of all files

Tags: php, directory, filesize

I have this script which works except for one small problem. Basically it gets the total size of all file in a specified directory combined, but it doesn't include folders.

My directory structure is like...

uploads
  -> client 01
  -> another client
  -> some other client

..ect.

Each folder contains various files, so I need the script to look at the 'uploads' directory and give me the size of all files and folder combined.

```
<?php      
$total = 0; //Total File Size
//Open the dir w/ opendir();
$filePath = "uploads/" . $_POST["USER_NAME"] . "/";
$d = opendir( $filePath ); //Or use some other path.
    if( $d ) {
while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $d ) ) ) { //Read the file list
   if (is_file($filePath.$file)){
$total+=filesize($filePath.$file);
   }
}
closedir( $d ); //Close the direcory
    echo number_format($total/1048576, 2);
    echo ' MB<br>';
}
else {
    echo "didn't work";
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Id use some SPL goodness...

```
$filePath = "uploads/" . $_POST["USER_NAME"];

$total = 0;
$d = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filePath), 
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($d as $file){
  $total += $file->getSize();
}

echo number_format($total/1048576, 2);
echo ' MB<br>';
```

Comment: Brilliant. Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to setup a recursive function

```
function getFolderSize($dir)
{
    $size = 0;
    if(is_dir($dir))
    {
        $files  = scandir($dir);
        foreach($files as $file)
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..')
                if(filetype($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file) == 'dir')
                    $size += getFolderSize($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
                else
                    $size += filesize($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
    }
    return $size;
}
```

**EDIT** there was a small bug in the code that I've fixed now

Comment: I did a quick comparison of my function to the function referred by @Shrinath and they are both fast; the RecursiveIteratorIterator is about 16% percent faster but uses about 11% more memory (with my off-the-cuff testing).  take with the appropriate amount of salt

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exec("du -s $filepath",$a);
$size = (int)$a[0]; // gives the size in 1k blocks
```

Be sure you validate `$_POST["USER_NAME"]` though, or you could end up with a nasty security bug.  (e.g. `$_POST["USER_NAME"] = "; rm -r /*"`)

Comment: This is absolutely what I'd do on the command-line. I'm kinda against exec unless truly necessary, though. I'd only do it this way if it was really slow to use @Patrick's answer by comparison.

Comment: @zanlok Fair enough.  Avoiding execs is good.  Still, I like the compactness of this solution.  Also, in the more general case there could be an issue of symbolic links and directories being counted more than once; `du` resolves these automatically.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. Thanks for the extra info.

Answer (score 0):

find keyword *directory* inside this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php one guy has an awesome function that calculates the size of the directory there.

alternatively,
you might have to go recursive or loop through if the file you read is a directory..

go through http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php