# PHP Listener for Uploaded Files

Tags: php, upload, listener

I am working on a project and am stuck at this part.  I am trying to write a script in PHP that will I guess scan my directories on my server.  Once a set of files is uploaded to a directory (Probably around 100 files uploaded) I want this script to then perform an event.

I am stuck on the code that will scan my directories while waiting for the files to be uploaded.

The structure of what I am looking for is this:

(Code to scan directories, waiting for files to be uploaded) -> Once files are uploaded -> Perform this event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

My server is hosted by Network Solutions if that helps. So I am not sure if I will be able to or have access to start a cron job.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to set up a cron job.

Comment: Someone retag as "gimme-teh-code"

Comment: You could also create a daemon if your hosting provider allows it.

Comment: Yeah, the trick here is to know when the file is done uploading. So: a chron job that scans the directory, only performing the action on files that have not been modified in a set period of time. ColdFusion has an awesome facility for this, if you're interested in switching.

Comment: why don't you just increase a counter on upload complete, check if counter >= countUploadSet, and then perform event if true...

Answer (score 0):

I send you on the way, but I'm not going to write all the code...

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929609/echo-the-combined-size-of-all-files) for a way to recursive search through a folder structure.

It will be simple to modify to check for new files.

Just set that up in a cron job, or if you don't have access to setup cron jobs, set it up to trigger on every nth page load so that way, as long as you have a decent amount of traffic, it will run regularly.